# Ошибка в консоле

Tags: javascript

В консоле выводится 8 (если несколько раз обновлять страницу то 8 появляется вместо 9). И почему то Math.floor не работает. Если поставить Math.ceil работает. Самое важное, хочу понять почему появляется 8 вместо 9.

[image: Ошибка в консоле]

```
const cont = document.querySelector('.container') //создаем переменную контейнер

const elemGenerator = (tag, classN, val) => { 
    if (!tag) return

    const element = document.createElement(tag)
    element.className = classN ? classN : ''

    if(val){

        element.innerText = val + ' '
        console.log('l');
    }

    return element
}

const getRandomColor = () => {
    return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (let k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
        const randomNumber = Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)) 

        const element = elemGenerator('span', 'cl', randomNumber)

        element.style.color = getRandomColor()

        cont.append(element)
        
    }
    cont.append(elemGenerator('br'))

}
```

Comment: `Math.random() * 50` возвращает число от 0 до 50, значит есть 2% шанс что число будет меньше единицы, значит `Math.abs` выдаст ноль, значит условие `if(val)` будет ложным и console.log не выполнится. А так как вы генерируете случайное число 9 раз, то шанс того, что хотя бы один раз выпадет ноль, равен примерно 17%

Comment: (не `Math.abs` а `Math.floor` конечно же)

Answer (score 0):

### Ошибка в коде, из-за способа генерации случайных чисел.

Вы используете следующую строку для генерации случайных чисел:

```
const randomNumber = Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50))
```

Проблема заключается в том, что Math.random() генерирует числа от 0 (включительно) до 1 (исключительно). Затем, умножая результат на 50 и округляя его вниз, вы получаете целое число в диапазоне от 0 до 49. Затем вы вызываете Math.abs(), чтобы убедиться, что число положительное.

> Из-за этой логики, есть вероятность, что значение randomNumber станет равным 0, и в этом случае вы видите значение 8, так как Math.abs(0) вернет 0.

Для генерации случайных чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 50, вы можете использовать следующую корректировку:

```
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
```

Этот код умножит случайное число от 0 до 1 на 50, а затем добавит 1, чтобы получить случайное число от 1 до 50, и значение 9 не будет потеряно.